# What is the best way to share files between EC2 servers?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am running multiple EC2 servers in different AWS regions. These are web servers running apache.

What is the best way to share files between the EC2 servers to keep the data in sync?

I heard about EFS but it doesn't support access from different regions, and also the performance doesn't work for me, since I don't have enough data to get their good performance tier.

Comment: What type of files? For multi-region, S3 may be the best option.

Comment: EFS *can* be used across regions, you just have to roll you own encapsulation and encryption, which I'm doing successfully over SSL (actually TLS, of course) with my old pal HAProxy on each end of the virtual link.   This is not, of course, suitable for interactive use, due to the relative sluggishness of the speed of light between regions -- you wouldn't want a web app back-end loading frequently-accessed resources across it -- but for sequential-write-heavy large file background tasks it's been impressively smooth.  More detail on your use case is definitely needed.

Comment: The files are pictures and thumbnails. I'm using a library to generate thumbnails, and the library needs a filesystem. So, storing directly to S3 will require extra work, and I also prefer something that just works with what I currently have.